# Destroy gameObject from another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having trouble trying to destroy the Enemy game object with **Script 2** from **Script 1**, which is a script containing common enemy data.

**Script 1**:

```
public class BaseEnemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    public int health = 4;
    public int speed = 0;
 
    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        health -= damage;
        Debug.Log("Damage Taken");
       
        if (health <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(??);
        }
    }
}
```

**Script 2**:

```
public class EnemyPlayerFollow : BaseEnemy
{
 
    public Transform player;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector2 movement;
 
    void Start()
    {
        rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
 
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 direction = player.position - transform.position;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        rb.rotation = angle;
        direction.Normalize();
        movement = direction;
 
        //if (health <= 0)
        //{
        //    Destroy(gameObject);
        //}
    }
 
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        moveCharacter(movement);
    }
 
    //public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    //{
    //    health -= damage;
    //    Debug.Log("Damage Taken");
    //}
 
    void moveCharacter(Vector2 direction)
    {
        rb.MovePosition((Vector2)transform.position + (direction * speed * Time.deltaTime));
    }
}
```

What I want to know, is how to modify **Script 1** to Destroy **Script 2** (Basically what to put here --> ??) when health <=0.

Comment: `Destroy(this)`

Comment: Destroy(this) destroyed just the script, so Destroy(this.gameObject) worked just fine. Thank you very much

Comment: Didn't you already have the solution there in script2 but commented out? `if (health <= 0){  Destroy(gameObject); }`

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER:

Was as easy to put Destroy(this.gameObject); on Script 1.
Thanks to "Chronicle" for the guidance.